# Sens du mot "patron" pour désigner client régulier (comme en anglais)

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais, synonymes

En anglais une signification du mot patron est

> a customer of a shop, restaurant, etc., especially a regular one. E.g. This car park is for patrons only.

Cette signification, je crois, n'existe pas en français. La retrouve-t-on auparavant ?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/300217/23719

Comment: @jlliagre Wow! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Le mot patron est en effet un "faux-ami" : ses deux significations principales en anglais sont très différentes du français, où le patron désigne une figure d'autorité ([et possède bien d'autres sens figurés](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/patron)).

1. > A person who gives financial or other support to a person, organization, cause, or activity.

Ici, on pourra employer le terme "**[mécène](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/m%C3%A9c%C3%A8ne/50041)**", qui est selon moi la traduction la plus exacte.

2. > A customer, especially a regular one, of a store, restaurant, or theater.

La définition est un peu plus vaste ici, on a donc l'embarras du choix. Le premier terme qui me vient à l'esprit est "**[habitué](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/habitu%C3%A9/38785)**". Dans la même idée, on peut également employer "client régulier".